# List all articles with their amounts at a certain date+time

Tags: mysql, group-by, table, max

I've got a table with articles, and their stock amount changes:

```
TABLE stock_history:
+------------+---------------------+--------+
| article_id | amount_at           | amount |
+------------+---------------------+--------+
|       0001 | 2016-01-19 08:00:00 |    100 |
|       0001 | 2016-02-20 08:00:00 |    500 |
|       0001 | 2016-03-21 08:00:00 |      0 |
|       0002 | 2016-01-17 08:00:00 |    999 |
|       0002 | 2016-02-23 08:00:00 |    500 |
|       0002 | 2016-04-21 08:00:00 |   5500 |
|       0003 | 2016-02-19 08:00:00 |   1000 |
|       0003 | 2016-03-03 08:00:00 |    500 |
|       0003 | 2016-03-21 08:00:00 |  -1500 |
+------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Now I need a query which lists all articles with their amounts at a certain `date+time`, for example `2016-03-01`:

I will need to use subqueries like here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-row.html

But I will need to use there SQL expressions somehow:

- `amount_at < '2016-03-01 00:00:00'`
- `MAX(amount_at)`
- `GROUP BY article_id`

The expected output should be like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+--------+
|       0001 | 2016-02-20 08:00:00 |    500 |
|       0002 | 2016-02-23 08:00:00 |    500 |
|       0003 | 2016-02-19 08:00:00 |   1000 |
+------------+---------------------+--------+
```

**note** I will need to join other tables, too, after, but that's another problem. :)

It's a little bit difficult...

Comment: You have found the parts you need, now mix them up ;) Jokes aside, have you tried some queries? What should the expected output be?

Comment: I've added the expected rows, the date+time is not really necessary...

Comment: For article 0003, what would be the expected value for the amount on 3/21?  If you used MAX, it would still be 1000.  Should it be the SUM of all values as of that date (so 0), or should it actually be -1500?

Answer (score 1):

I you don't care about the time in the result it's pretty easy:

```
select article_id, sum(amount)
from stock_history 
where amount_at <= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
group by article_id
```

If you want time, you need to determine which time you should present. If you want the same time as in the `where` clause you can just add it since it is a constant:

```
select article_id, '2016-03-01 00:00:00', sum(amount)
from stock_history 
where amount_at <= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
group by article_id
```

Assuming it is the last time before this time you can map all times to this time with a derived table and use that:

```
select a.article_id, b.amount_at, sum(a.amount)
from stock_history a
join ( select article_id, max(amount_at) as amount_at 
       from stock_history 
       where amount_at <= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
       group by article_id
) as b
    on a.rticle_id = b.article_id
   and a.amount_at <= b.amount_at
group by a.article_id, b.amount_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easily solved with window functions in other DBMS that have implemented these features, like PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2 or with a `LATERAL` join inj Postgres (or the similar `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` in SQL Server). In MySQL, it's not trivial but can be done. My favourite way of doing this kind of queries:

```
select 
    d.article_id, s.amount_at, s.amount
from 
    ( select article_id
      from stock_history 
      group by article_id
    ) as d                      -- the basis of the query. If there is a table
                                -- that has artcile_id as PK, use that instead
  join
    stock_history as s          -- where we'll get the data from
  on  s.article_id = d.article_id
  and s.amount_at  = 
          ( select si.amount_at
            from stock_history as si
            where si.amount_at < '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
            order by si.amount_at desc
            limit 1
          ) ;
```

Assuming that `(article_id, amount_at)` has a `UNIQUE` constraint, the query will return one row per `article_id` (or none for those artciles that there is no row before the wanted date). If there is another unique or `PRIMARY KEY`you want to use instead, replace this part:

```
  on  s.article_id = d.article_id
  and s.amount_at  = 
          ( select si.amount_at
          ...
```

with:

```
  on  s.PK =
          ( select si.PK
          ...
```